# jqGrid: using a predefined formatter inside a custom formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I would like to use a predefined formatter inside a custom formatter.

For example, this is the colModel:

```
colModel: [
  ...
  { name: 'col1', formatter: myFormatter }
  ...
]
```

and this is the formatter:

```
function myFormatter(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
  if (typeof cellValue === 'number') {
    // Here I want to call the "currency" predefined formatter on the cellValue

  } else {
    return 'No number to display';
  }
}
```

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you could do that by calling

```
return $.fmatter.util.NumberFormat(cellValue, $.jgrid.formatter.currency)
```